# Can you update yum packages one at a time?

Tags: centos, vps, yum

My low memory box running CentOS cannot be updated, since yum is getting killed due to high memory usage. Is there a way to automatically update all packages, one at a time instead of updating everything at once?

Comment: Get a bigger box - seriously.

Comment: It's only a supporting box, so when running, it's only using 20-50% of the RAM. Upgrading wouldn't make sense.

Comment: then add some swap

Comment: I second that, try adding swap in addition to anything else you try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `async` settings for `yum` repositories by adding `async=0` to prevent metadata and packages from being downloaded in parallel.

For example, `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/...
async=0
```

Alternatively, you should be able to add this to the `[main]` section of `/etc/yum.conf` to override the default settings.

If this is still an issue; you may need to script this to execute `yum install ...` for each package individually.

```
while read pkg_name; do yum install -y "$pkg_name"; done < <(yum check-update | awk '/^\s*$/,0 { print $1 }')
```

This will run `yum check-update` to list all packages awaiting update and install each of them individually.